# Swiper.js: Slides are Stacking Vertically and Swiping to Empty Page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I'm currently using Swiper.js in my Hero section. However, I'm experiencing an issue where the slides are stacking vertically on the same page, and when I attempt to swipe, it navigates to an empty page.

I've followed the documentation carefully, but I'm not sure what's causing this behavior. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Are there any known solutions or common mistakes I should be aware of? I am a beginner so it could be a simple issue.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import "./Hero.css";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper } from "swiper/react";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar/SearchBar";
const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <section className="hero-wrapper">
      <Swiper slidesPerView={1}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}>
        <SwiperSlide>
          // slide
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
         // slide
        </SwiperSlide>

      </Swiper>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Consider checking you have included the Swiper CSS.